# Using multiValue parameter with ArcPy and ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-toolbox, multi-values

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I want to make a Python toolbox tool (*.pyt) where I put for input multiple layer's and to apply a buffer for every input. I want every buffer to put another distance. After I put the input layer's to appear another window where to specify the distance for buffer.

Is it possible?

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""
    Layers=arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Layers",
        name="Layer",
        direction="Input",
        parameterType="Required",
        datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
        multiValue="True")
    parameter = [Layers]
    return parameter

def execute(self, parameter, messages):
    """The source code of the tool."""
    parameter=params[0].valueAsText
```

[image]

Comment: If you are creating a python toolbox then you want to create a value table parameter to capture layer/distance combinations.

Comment: Are you writing a Python script tool (tbx) or Python Toolbox tool (pyt)?

Comment: A Python Toolbox tool (pyt)

Comment: Please don't respond to requests for additional information as a comment, [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/433331/edit) to include the info.

Comment: Could you please provide the def execute part of the code as well? I've been struggling with the same issue. I have multiple layers with different buffer distances and I want to get multiple outputs with the different buffers.

Answer (score 2):

The following sets up a value table in a python toolbox which takes layers and allows you to set distances that would feed into a buffer tool.

```py
def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""
    p0 =arcpy.Parameter(displayName="Layers",name="Layer",direction="Input",parameterType="Required",datatype="GPValueTable",multiValue="True")
    p0.columns = [["GPFeatureLayer", "Layers"], ["GPLong", "Buffer Distance"]] # Defines the structure of the table
    p0.filters[0].list = ['POINT','POLYLINE'] # Limits the Featurelayers to be only point or polyline
    p0.filters[1].type = 'Range' # sets the filter on the buffer to be a range
    p0.filters[1].list = [1,100] # only buffers distances between 1 and 100 (inclusive) can be set
    params = [p0]
    return params
```

The interface looks like this (note error symbol as it is capturing the incorrect buffer value:

[image: Tool interface]